# How to identify which variable causes the UI refreshing?

Tags: swiftui

In general, variable marked as `@State @ObservedObject @StateObject @FetchRequest` can cause the UI refreshing. But in a big source, how to identify which variable cause the UI refreshing?

In most cases, onChange will do it, but in some cases, such as coredata, it's hard.

Comment: In reactive paradigm you should not rely on that.

Comment: I just want to do some trouble shouting.

Comment: You can found that there are so many questions about this concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SwiftUI provides a special, debug-only method call we can use to identify what change caused a view to reload itself.

Updated for Xcode 13.0

```
var body: some View {
        print(Self._printChanges())
        return Text("Hello")
    }
```

updated:

```
var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        Text("Hello")
    }
```